# How do I f.Type()=="string" directly using golang reflect?

Tags: go

Full code is here:
https://pastebin.com/xC1uQVBC

```
   type UDD struct {
                        A string //content = "John"
                        B string //content = "Male"
                        C string //content = "12345678"
                        D int64 //content = ""
                        E uint64 //content = ""
                        Z string //content = "FIrst time user"
   }


    reflect_UDD := reflect.ValueOf(&UDD).Elem()
    typeOf_UDD := reflect_UDD.Type()




    for i := 0; i < reflect_UDD.NumField(); i++ {
           f := reflect_UDD.Field(i)

           if(f.Type()==reflect.TypeOf("string")){ 
                //i would like to f.Type()=="string" directly... 
                //how is this possible and also for uint64 and int64 etc
           }
     }
```

Basically, I would like to do something along the lines of

```
f.Type()=="string"
```

or

```
f.Type()=="uint64"
```

or

```
f.Type()=="int64"
```

directly instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `f.Type()` to `f.Kind()`, then use reflect Type to do judgement, supported types could be found https://godoc.org/reflect#Kind.
please see full example https://play.golang.org/p/Zydi7t3UBNJ

```
      switch f.Kind() {
    case reflect.Int64:
        fmt.Println("got int64")
    case reflect.String:
        fmt.Println("got string")
    case reflect.Uint64:
        fmt.Println("got Unit64")
    default:
        fmt.Println("found nothing")        
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare variables for the types of interest. It's usually best to do this at package level.

```
var ( 
  stringType = reflect.TypeOf("")
  uint64Type = reflect.TypeOf(uint64(0))
  ... and so on
)
```

Compare to these types:

```
if f.Type() == stringType { 
    ...
}
```

It's not possible to use `f.Type()== "string"` because strings are not assignable to reflect.Type values or vice versa.

Another option is to call [Type.String()](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.String), but it's usually better to compare types than strings:

```
if f.Type().String == "string" { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f.Type().Kind().String()=="Uint64"
```

See [reflect.Kind](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind)